# Protocol for verifying novel compression algorithm?

Tags: protocol-design, compression

By the pigeonhole principle, we can demonstrate that arbitrary lengths of random data are uncompressible in the general case.

But let us imagine that I claim that I have created an oracle that can compress arbitrary random data by a certain ratio.

In such a case, I don't want to show you the internal details of my oracle, because you will steal its awesome secrets.  But I am willing to generate hashes for you.  I am also willing to use my oracle to compress and/or decompress any file that you give me, or do any other reasonable thing that does not disclose the internal details of the oracle.

Design a protocol that lets me prove that my oracle works as I claim, without actually revealing the algorithm it uses.

If that can't be done, then design a protocol that requires me to trust a disinterested third party, as little as I possibly can.

A little more formally: I want to demonstrate, to an arbitrary likelihood, that I possess an invertible bijective function $F$,  in which $F(x) = y$, $F^{-1}(y) = x$, and $F^{-1}(F(x)) = x$, without revealing $F$ or $F^{-1}$.  Can a protocol be designed that permits me to prove the existence of $F$ and $F^{-1}$ without revealing them?  If not, what is the least extent to which a third party would need to know $F$ or $F^{-1}$?

This isn't a homework question, just a possibly interesting thought experiment to people who understand crypto better than I do.

Comment: I can confirm that this is not a homework question, in case anyone wonders.  :-D

Comment: The proof would also need to show that $|F(x)| < |x|$, otherwise the existence of such an $F$ is trivial...

Comment: @poncho well yes, but I didn't necessarily require that as part of the protocol, because I imagined that proof of a particular algorithm's existence might lend itself to other situations besides compressibility.

Comment: @poncho For example, imagine that I might claim that I can crack any one-time pad.  I don't want to teach you how I do that, though.  In that case, the length condition might or might not hold.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the only solution that occurs to me is:

- The verifier (V), that is, the guy who is skeptical about the existence of such an algorithm, selects an FHE (Fully Homomorphic Encryption) algorithm and public/private key; he publishes the algorithm and public key (but keeps the private key secret)
- The prover (P), that is, the guy with the secret algorithm, implements his algorithm (both $F$ and $F^{-1}$) using the FHE algorithm and public key
- V selects a value $x$ and a direction bit $d$.  He encrypts $x$ with his public key and gives both $E(x)$ and $d$ to P
- If $d=0$, $P$ computes (using his FHE implementation) the value $E(F(x))$; if $d=1$, $P$ computes the value $E(F^{-1}(x))$.  In either case, he sends that value back to V
- V decrypts the value, recovering either $F(x)$ or $F^{-1}(x)$

With Oracle access to $F, F^{-1}$, $V$ can easily verify the claims; for example, he can pick a random sequence $X_0, X_1, ..., X_{n-1}$ and ask for $Y_i=F(X_i)$; he can then make sure that $|Y_i| < |X_i|$ and then ask for (in a random order) $F^{-1}(Y_i)$ and verify that is, in fact, $X_i$.  And, because everything P has access to is encrypted, his best cheating strategy succeeds with probability $1/n!$ if $P$ selects a random sequence of length $n$.

Issues:

- This gives V Oracle access to the actual inputs/outputs of $F, F^{-1}$
- The FHE encryption system has the further requirement that someone with the private key can't, by looking at a ciphertext, determine what computations lead to that ciphertext.  I don't believe this is hard to achieve, but is a nonstandard assumption.